# What is the correct preposition in "a real genius in/for/at mathematics"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Which of the following is correct grammatically?

1. He has a real genius ***in*** mathematics.
2. He has a real genius ***for*** mathematics.
3. He has a real genius ***at*** mathematics.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Please show the research you've done to try to answer the question yourself and why you have doubts about the possible answers.  Also consider asking on English Lanugage Learners.

Comment: You may want to [look at a dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/genius) -- the first set of examples shows "that woman has a genius for organization" -- exactly the construct you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

> 'He has a real genius for mathematics'

would be correct grammatically. Having a genius for something indicates having a flair or skill for something. Read more
[here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-a-genius-for-doing-something).

"in" would not be valid with "has".

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a person, following statement could be used,

> He is a real genius in mathematics.

The word genius can be used as noun or adjective.

To use ‘genius’ as a noun, you have to use the word as if it is a ‘thing’

> He is a football genius.
>
> That was a stroke of genius.

To use ‘genius’ as an adjective, you have to use the word as if you were describing something.

> He comes up with some amazing, genius ideas!

Comment: Can you explain why, or provide a link to your sources?  What's wrong with the OP's "he has a real genius for mathematics"?

Comment: I'm trying to say that you need to include explanations and links in your answer.